# no permissions found in manifest for 3

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, android-manifest, android-permissions

im looking to ask for permission to access location i tried other methodes like location and geo location but setteled on using permission_handler: ^11.2.0 package in flutter 3
i installed the needed dependencies and added the permisions in the AndroidManifest.xml

it returns
No permissions found in manifest for: []3
permission not granted

im testing on android 13 device.

here is my flutter code snipt:

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
.
.
 PrimaryBtn(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 55,
  buttonText: "ACCESS LOCATION",
  icon: 'assets/icons/map-pin.svg',
  iconSize: 35,
  onTap: () {
   checkPermission(Permission.location, context);
},
.
.
.
 Future<void> checkPermission(
  Permission permission, BuildContext context) async {
  try {
    final status = await permission.request();
    if (status.isGranted) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Permission is Granted"),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text("Permission is not Granted"),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        ),
      );
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error while requesting permission: $e");
    // Handle the error as needed
  }
}
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

here's few links i consulted
[How to solve "No permissions found in manifest for: []9" in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74826687/how-to-solve-no-permissions-found-in-manifest-for-9-in-flutter)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57622704/no-permissions-found-in-manifest-android